# Cannot display first child of a node

Tags: javascript, xml

Missing data when parsing an xml_file using javascript.
I am trying to display the first child from an xml-file in the webbrowser, using HTML and Javascript. The problem is, the name of the first child does not appear.
Note: I am using google Chrome.
[image]
Javascript:

```
     <title>Read First Child</title>
        <xml ID="Schriftsteller" SRC="D:\files\files\Schriftsteller.xml"></xml>
           <script language="JavaScript">

           function loadXMLDoc("D:\files\files\javascriptparser.html")
              {
                 var xmlDoc;
                 if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
                 {
                  xmlDoc=new window.XMLHttpRequest();
                  xmlDoc.open("GET","D:\files\files\javascriptparser.html",false);
                  xmlDoc.send("");
                  return xmlDoc.responseXML;
                 }
                 // IE 5 and IE 6
                  else if (ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM"))
                  {
                   xmlDoc=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
                   xmlDoc.async=false;
                   xmlDoc.load(XMLname);
                   return xmlDoc;
                  }
                    alert("Error loading document!");
                    return null;
              }

              function findWriter() 
              {
                 var Schriftsteller, schriftstellerKnoten, SpracheKnoten;
                 var FüllerKnoten, DichtungKnoten, Anzeige;

                 myXML = document.all("D:\files\files\Schriftsteller.xml").XMLDocument;
                 SchriftstellerKnoten = myXML.documentElement;
                 SpracheKnoten = SchriftstellerKnoten.firstChild;
                 DichtungKnoten = SpracheKnoten.firstChild;
                 FüllerKnoten = DichtungKnoten.firstChild;
                 NameNode = FüllerKnoten.firstChild;
                 Anzeige = NameNode.firstChild.nodeValue;
                 Documentar.show.me.value = Anzeige;
              }
           </script>
               <span ID="blueBack">Read firstChild</span>
               <div>
               <form name="show">
               <input type=text name="me">
               <input type="button" value="Display Writer"
                onClick="findWriter()">
               </form>
               </div>
               </body>
```

Comment: Did you ckeck the javascript error console ofor errorsß

Comment: @reporter: how can i check the errors in the console. please see what is displayed in the web page in the attached image

Comment: I'm unable to see that image, because the content is bloked by company's content filter. You can opening the console as follos: Click on a symbol right side from the adress bar. Then select 'tools' and then click on 'Javascript console'.

Comment: @reporter: the javascript console displays:(1) no element found (2)firefox can not establish a connection to the sever at ws://sockets.ny.stackexchange.com/ and other errors.....but still i can not recognize where my mistake is

Comment: Can yu provide an example xml-file?

Answer (score 0):

`xmlDoc.open("GET",D:\files\files\javascriptparser.html,false);`

This is the statement you have used. The Path of the file is a string. It should be enclosed in quotes like so:

`xmlDoc.open("GET","D:\files\files\javascriptparser.html",false);`

Comment: i did as suggested but, but, the result is the same

Comment: can you check in the error console and let me know the error?

Comment: the javascript console displays:(1) no element found (2)firefox can not establish a connection to the server at ws://sockets.ny.stackexchange.com/ and other errors.....but still i can not recognize where my mistake is

Comment: The `findWriter()` function is syntactically incorrect. There are semicolons missing for one thing.

Comment: i corrected findWriter() function but still the page does not display the intended result

Comment: `loadXMLDoc()` is not called anywhere.

Comment: The function needs to be called to be invoked. Call it inside `findWriter()`.

Comment: `loadXMLDoc()` cannot be defined with a signature like `function loadXMLDoc("D:\files\files\javascriptparser.html")`. It has to be `function loadXMLDoc(var path)`.